# Measuring the similarity between two objects across multiple dimensions (categories)

Tags: r, matrix, similarity, lda

The question may be better suited for a board like cross-validated, but I am asking here to elicit some inputs.

I'm trying to construct a crude measure to gauge the similarity between any pairs of objects across multiple dimensions (or categories (for example, they can be percentages of GDP across economic sectors or students' grades in multiple subjects)).

Some potential candidates I have in mind are latent topics approach from the LDA (Latent Dirichlet Allocation), which assign (non-zero) probabilities for each unit across a list of K clusters, and word2vec that measures the similarity between any two corpora based on the vectorized scores of their texts. But given that the objects I want to deal with usually have a fixed number of categories (e.g., academy subjects, economic sectors) and bounded distribution (say between 0 and 100). I wonder what will be a more appropriate measure for this task? A measure between 0 and 1 will be ideal.

Also, I want to do this in a pairwise manner, so that for each unit from a total of N units, the similarity measure is calculated for each unit in comparison to the rest of the N-1 units. For example, s11 (which is just 1), s12, s13, s14, their scores may be different from s21, s22, s23, s24, so on and so forth. Eventually, I want to rearrange it into an N times N matrix for further processing.

I provide export statistics (4 main commodity categories from the WTO database) below as an example, hoping to use this example to find a way to (1) construct a crude measure for comparing trade (export) profile similarity between any country pairs and (2) arrange the output into a 4 by 4 matrix.

```css
profile = data.frame("country" = c("Afghanistan", "Albania", "Belgium", "Canada"),
"Agricultural products"=c(65.8, 11, 10.9, 15.3), 
"Manufactures" = c(5.9, 69.7, 75.7, 47.9), 
"Fuels and mining products" = c(1, 19.2, 12.6, 29), 
"Others"=c(27.3, 0.7, 0.9, 7.8)
)
```

Hope someone could share his/her insights with me.

Comment: check out the `fuzzyjoin` package

Answer (score 1):

LDA is not the droid you are looking for here.  If you just have vector data that you want to make pairwise comparisons for, a good place to start would be cosine similarity.  As long as your data isn't too high-dimensional, cosine similarity will enable you to find pairs of countries, for instance, that have similar trading habits.